# Xcode 6.1.3 can't change simulated screen size

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

Using Xcode 6.3.1 I needed to simulate sizes to make the app compatible with older devices, I went to menu just to find that I can't select different screen sizes.

What am I missing?

[image: Missing options]

**EDIT**

Another project, this time using size classes: [image: With size class]

This option makes the entire storyboard use a specific screen size so I can see what is happening at design time

Maybe this is intended? To make people use size classes?

Comment: What is the deployment target?  I expect Xcode is smart enough to know what devices that version of iOS is capable of running on.

Comment: Deployment target 6.0, not using size classes and using auto layout

Comment: I have the same problem.  Restarting Xcode didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, after some time (almost a year) I still haven't found a solution. The new preview is supposed to replace the old "Simulated Screen".

This is how you enable it:
[image]

And this is how you add any number of devices side-by-side:
[image]

The reason they added this is because you can now see many resolutions at the same time and see better what you build and how it will look in the various devices available.

I don't agree with that, I still miss the "Simulated Screen". I think it was a better solution, but they removed. We have to deal with it.

---

Before this turns into a race to see who gets the bounty I'm going to close this.

@mcatach : Thats not the point. Xcode before 6.3.1 allowed you to see your storyboard in the interface builder with the device size you wanted. So we could use size classes and see in a particular resolution how it should look.

@aman.sood : This wont do. Changing the development target will not do anything to the interface builder, only remove size classes on older targets. Preview helps, but could be better. Using actual device is **required** to publish but it's not a solution to see different resolutions, that would mean you need at least 6 devices (7 with iPad mini).

Comment: looks like you haven't read the full answer. I had given you with all possible ways. What you had missed is to check out "Second option is to use Preview in Xcode. That will provide you with different configuration without running your app. Check out this video for more details." Which is exactly the same for which you have marked answer for.

Comment: Regarding the the first option setting development target that gives you option for different screen sizes while running in simulator. Not sure why are you relating it with interface builder as you did mentioned it in your question

Comment: The whole point of the question was to see all the storyboard with a selected screen size. That could be done before and now it cannot. Changing the target will not enable a feature Xcode had removed. The "preview" solution, as stated, works but is not the answer to this problem.

Comment: What I've failed to explain is: this question doesn't have a answer. You can't work on the storyboard in a specific screen size. You can only preview the result of one screen at a time

Comment: Anyway I don't see difference in your answer and mine. Second option + video tutorial and your answer is exactly the same. And you still marked my answer as not useful was strange to me.

Comment: The thing that I don't understand is, if they removed "Simulated Screen", why do we still have the menu option that has an extension icon but doesn't extend?  It still seems like a bug to me.

Comment: @hatten on Xcode 6.3.1 that menu was still there. But on newer versions that item is no longer available

Comment: @NicosKaralis, I have Xcode 7.2.1, and I still have that menu.

Comment: @hattenn strange, mine doesn't show `7.2.1 (7C1002)`

Comment: @NicosKaralis, I have the exact same build, I wonder what the reason is. When I turn off size classes, I get the "Simulated Screen" menu that is broken.

Answer (score -1):

Couple of things you can do

- Use Xcode by setting active schema for different devices like iPhone 4,iPhone 6s etc. But these drop down option will be available as per your deployment target settings selection [image]
- Second option is to use Preview in Xcode. That will provide you with different configuration without running your app. Check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3sDU56ojFv4) for more details.
- And last is to use actual device which only one uses when there is device specific issue.

Answer (score -1):

When you're using size classes you will not see specific resolutions sizes. You need to design your screens based on global sizes (Compact/Regular/Any). You can use Any to fit any possible height/width.

So, my advice is to decide if you want to support iPhone and/or iPad, and then start to draw your screens.